# interactive mouse pointer location in matlab

Tags: matlab, mouse, geometry, interactive

friends

i have a problem , i am writing a code for routing in network , specifically i want to implement Aodv protocol in matlab, now i want to add some graphical  parts to my code .

and suppose that on a 1000*1000 zeros image , we have some nodes(router) that are shown by a square with size 15*15 and white color , so we have some white parts in zero image ,

now i wrote a function to draw a circle around each parts with specific radii ,         but because  we have alots of nodes , our image will be very dirty  , **so i want you to help me to change this function that when mouse pointer points to each of this white parts  , a circle is shown  and when we move mouse pointer to another part this circle will be hidden .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the figure window [callbacks](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/button-down-callback-function.html#buhztrs-16).
See [the Figure object](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html?refresh=true) and Control+F to find the word 'Callback', this will show you the callbacks available for use.
Using these methods you can then write an application to do as you asked.

```
set(gcf, 'UserData', {some, data, my, callbacks, need});
set(gcf,'ButtonDownFcn',@myMouseBtnDownCallback);
set(gcf,'windowbuttonmotionfcn',@myMouseMoveCallback);
set(gcf,'windowbuttonupfcn',@myMouseBtnUpCallback);

function myMouseBtnDownCallback(src, eventdata)
function myMouseMoveCallback(src,eventdata,r)
function myMouseBtnUpCallback(src,evendata)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with sufficiently clever use of the `WindowButtonMotionFcn` property of a figure and the `CurrentPoint` property of an axis.

Given an image with black background and some white areas within it, here generated by randomly seeding 5 center points and then dilating them to the desired size, you can use the `WindowButtonMotionFcn` callback to test if the cursor is 1) within the image dimensions and 2) over a white spot.  If so, draw a circle in the image axes over the white square.  Similar work can be done for any input image though you might have to do some pre-processing to determine where the center of your regions are if the image is supplied rather than generated within the function.

Code:

```
function circlePointer

% Initialize figure and axes within figure window
fig = figure('Position', [200 200 600 600], 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @MouseOverFcn);
ax = axes('Parent', fig, 'Position', [0.05 0.05 .90 .90], ...
    'XLim', [0.5 1000.5], 'YLim', [0.5 1000.5]);

% Make black image with random white squares
img = zeros(1000, 1000);
whiteSquares = randperm(1000, 10);
whiteSquares = reshape(whiteSquares, [], 2);
for k = 1:size(whiteSquares, 1);
    img(whiteSquares(k, 1), whiteSquares(k,2)) = 1;
end
halfSquareSize = 7; % Size of one side of the square to be drawn, divided by 2
img = bwmorph(img, 'dilate', halfSquareSize);

% Display image in axes generated above
imagesc(1:1000, 1:1000, img, 'Parent', ax);
set(ax, 'XTick', [], 'YTick', []);
colormap('gray');


% Use MouseOverFcn to determine where the cursor is currently pointing when
% positioned in the figure window. 
% If the cursor is within the image axes and is hovered over a white
% square, then draw a red circle around that square.  If one or both of
% these conditions is not met, clear out all of the previously-drawn
% circles. 
    function MouseOverFcn(varargin)

        PostNow = round(get(ax, 'CurrentPoint'));

        if all(PostNow(1, 1:2) < 1000) && all(PostNow(1, 1:2) > 1)
            if (img(PostNow(1,2), PostNow(1,1)) == 1)
                % Overlay circle

                % Find which square is the one currently hovered over by
                % the cursor
                nearestSquare = knnsearch(whiteSquares, [PostNow(1,2) PostNow(1,1)]);

                % Draw a circle with circRad centered on the current square
                set(ax, 'NextPlot', 'add');
                circRad = 30; % circle radius in image axis units
                circCent = [whiteSquares(nearestSquare, 2), whiteSquares(nearestSquare, 1)];
                circAngle = [0:.2:(2*pi) 0];
                [circPtsX, circPtsY] = pol2cart(circAngle, circRad*ones(1, length(circAngle)));
                plot(circPtsX+circCent(1), circPtsY+circCent(2), 'r', 'Tag', 'drawnCircles');
                set(ax, 'NextPlot', 'replace');

            else
                % If cursor is not currently over a white square in the
                % image, clear all previously drawn circles
                delete(findobj('Tag', 'drawnCircles'));

            end

        else
            % If cursor is not currently over the image,
            % clear all previously drawn circles
            delete(findobj('Tag', 'drawnCircles'));
        end

    end

end
```

Comment: Hi again , and thanks a lot for your help , but why when i read img with imread function to read a created image (zeros background and some small white square ), this code has errors

Comment: "...this code has errors," is not very helpful.  Please provide the actual error message if you would like the problem to be addressed.   Can you also provide the test image that you are using?  My guess is that the values in your image are not between 0 and 1 but rather 0 and 255, so the test `if (img(PostNow(1,2), PostNow(1,1)) == 1)` will never be true because 'white' in your image is equal to 255, not 1, as presumed here.

Answer (score 0):

specifically  i change code like this but **when i point to white parts , does not appear any  circle around that part** .(my image is test 2 , a zero image with some white parts )

```
  function circlePointer
           fig = figure( 'WindowButtonMotionFcn', @MouseOverFcn);
           ax = axes('Parent', fig, 'Position', [0.05 0.05 .90 .90], ...
          'XLim', [0.5 1000.5], 'YLim', [0.5 1000.5]);
           img=imread('test2.jpg');
           img=img(:,:,1);
           img=im2double(img);
           [r,c]=size(img);
           imagesc(1:r, 1:c, img, 'Parent', ax);
           set(ax, 'XTick', [], 'YTick', []);
           colormap('gray');


function MouseOverFcn(varargin)

    PostNow = round(get(ax, 'CurrentPoint'));

    if all(PostNow(1, 1) < c) && all(PostNow(1, 1:2) > 1) && all(PostNow(1, 2) < r)
        if (img(PostNow(1,2), PostNow(1,1)) == 1)

        % this function (insert shape) put a circle arround  a pointed pixel        

        img=insertShape(img, 'circle', [PostNow(1, 1) PostNow(1, 1) 300],'Color',{'red'},'Opacity', .4);
        imshow(img)

        else
            % If cursor is not currently over a white square in the
            % image, clear all previously drawn circles
            delete(findobj('Tag', 'drawnCircles'));

        end

    else
        % If cursor is not currently over the image,
        % clear all previously drawn circles
        delete(findobj('Tag', 'drawnCircles'));
    end

end
end
```